# No output in django project

Tags: python, django

I am new to django.

I wrote a simple django app called blog, every thing is goes correct. but when i run the there is no outout.

Here is my code.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Blog_post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    auther = models.CharField(max_length=250)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog_post

def index(request):
    posts = Blog_post.objects.all()
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render (request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World </h1>
     {{x}}

    {% for post in posts %}
        {{title}}

    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index')
]
```

Comment: What do you mean with no output?. You can't access to the app with browser?. You can't see any log in terminal?.

Comment: @BlueSun, there are two error in index.html file. They are {{x}} and {{title}}

Comment: thanks, for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to see the title for the blog posts:

Replace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World </h1>
     {{x}}

    {% for post in posts %}
        {{title}}

    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

With:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World </h1>
     {{x}}

    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.title }}

    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help